# Integration Services error with OLEDB Oracle 11g when testing connection

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, ssis, etl

I get the following error when i try to test the connection with my Oracle DB on Integration Services project with microsoft OLE DB for provider Oracle integration services:

> Test connection failed because of an error in initializing provider.
>   Oracle client and networking components were not found. These
>   components are supplied by Oracle Corporation and are part of the
>   Oracle Version 7.3.3 or later client software installation.
>
> Provider is unable to function until these components are installed.

I'm currently using Visual Studio 2019 with Integration services extencios 3.2.2 and my DB its:

```
64bit Production PL/SQL Release 11.2.0.2.0 - 
Production "CORE    11.2.0.2.0  Production" TNS for 64-bit Windows: Version
11.2.0.2.0 - Production 
NLSRTL Version 11.2.0.2.0 - Production
```

How can I connect my database to my ETL?

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you need to install 32 bit Oracle OLEDB provider. Visual Studio is 32 bit and thus SSIS editor is 32 bit and uses 32 bit provider. When running SSIS runs as 64 bit (by default) but editor is 32 bit.